# error with instantiating a SQL statement (Java) (JDBC)

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, jdbc

I've been trying to practice using JDBC in netbeans but i'm stuck with a little problem, now i loaded a driver, established a connection to SQL but for some reason my SQL statement isn't working, i'll be glad if anyone can bear with me

```
public void dbTest() {
    try {
        Class.forName(
                "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException |
            IllegalAccessException |
            ClassNotFoundException e) {
    }

    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/", "root", "explore");
            Statement statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement()) {
        String query = "select first_name, last_name"
                + " from sakila.customer "
                + "where address_id < 10";
        try (ResultSet resultset =
                statement.executeQuery(query)) {
            while (resultset.next()) {
                String firstName =
                        resultset.getString("first_name");
                String lastName =
                        resultset.getString("last_name");
                System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }
}
```

this line of code is causing me the trouble

```
Statement statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement()
```

Thanks!!

Comment: When you say it is causing you trouble what do you mean? It is throwing an exception? It won't let you compile?

Comment: Most probably you are not using `java.sql.Statement`. you probably are using 'java.beans.Statement'

Comment: @KevinD it won't let me compile

Comment: @PremGenError i'm using `java.beans.Statement` but how will it make a difference ?

Comment: you should use `java.sql.Statement` to execute quries through JDBC

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace ?

Comment: Yeah i noticed it earlier :) thanks!

Comment: please provide the error and one thing you might want to do is add e.printStackTrace(); inside your catch block.

Comment: You don't need the cast either. `Statement stmt = connnection.createStatement()` is enough.

Comment: `Connection.createStatement` will always return `java.sql.Statement`. Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createStatement%28%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As most of the comments states, you should use `java.sql.Statement` and not `java.beans.Statement`.

Another thing i notice with your code is that you are querying and you have not specified from which database these operation should be done which will lead you to `SQLException`. So again you will have to change the url string from `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"` to `"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name"`.

Hope this helps.